# Using UNNEST with a JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, naming-conventions, unnest

I want to be able to use `unnest()` function in PostgreSQL in a complicated SQL query that has many `JOIN`s. Here's the example query:

```
SELECT 9 as keyword_id, COUNT(DISTINCT mentions.id) as total, tags.parent_id as tag_id
FROM mentions
INNER JOIN taggings ON taggings.mention_id = mentions.id
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id
WHERE mentions.taglist && ARRAY[9] AND mentions.search_id = 3
GROUP BY tags.parent_id
```

I want to eliminate the `taggings` table here, because my `mentions` table has an **integer array** field named **taglist** that consists of all linked tag ids of `mentions`.

I tried following:

```
SELECT 9 as keyword_id, COUNT(DISTINCT mentions.id) as total, tags.parent_id as tag_id 
FROM mentions 
INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id IN (SELECT unnest(taglist))
WHERE mentions.taglist && ARRAY[9] AND mentions.search_id = 3 
GROUP BY tags.parent_id
```

This works but brings different results than the first query.

So what I want to do is to use the result of the `SELECT unnest(taglist)` in a `JOIN` query to compensate for the `taggings` table.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** `taglist` is the same set as the respective list of tag ids of mention.

Comment: `mentions table has an integer array field named taglist that includes tag ids of mention.` Please define "includes". Is `taglist` exactly the same set as the respective list of tag ids of mention?

Comment: Yes, `taglist` is the same set as the respective list of tag ids of mention. I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, your query might work like this (not entirely sure about the objective of this query):

```
SELECT 9 AS keyword_id, count(DISTINCT m.id) AS total, t.parent_id AS tag_id
FROM  (
    SELECT  unnest(m.taglist) AS tag_id
    FROM    mentions m
    WHERE   m.search_id = 3
    AND     9 = ANY (m.taglist)
    ) m 
JOIN   tags t  USING (tag_id) -- assumes tag.tag_id!
GROUP  BY t.parent_id;
```

However, it seems to me you are going in the wrong direction here. Normally one would remove the redundant array `taglist` and keep the normalized database schema. Then your original query should serve well, only shortened the syntax with aliases:

```
SELECT 9 AS keyword_id, count(DISTINCT m.id) AS total, t.parent_id AS tag_id
FROM   mentions m
JOIN   taggings mt ON mt.mention_id = m.id
JOIN   tags     t  ON t.id = mt.tag_id
WHERE  9 = ANY (m.taglist)
AND    m.search_id = 3
GROUP  BY t.parent_id;
```

#### Unravel the mystery

`<rant>`
The root cause for your "different results" is the unfortunate naming convention that some *intellectually challenged ORMs* impose on people.
I am speaking of `id` as column name. Never use this anti-pattern in a database with more than one table. Right, that means basically *any* database. As soon as you join a bunch of tables (that's what you *do* in a database) you end up with a bunch of columns named `id`. Utterly pointless.
The ID column of a table named `tag` should be **`tag_id`** (unless there is another descriptive name). Never `id`.
`</rant>`

Your query inadvertently counts `tags` instead of `mentions`:

```
SELECT 25 AS keyword_id, count(m.id) AS total, t.parent_id AS tag_id
FROM  (
    SELECT unnest(m.taglist) AS id
    FROM   mentions m
    WHERE  m.search_id = 4
    AND    25 = ANY (m.taglist)
    ) m
JOIN   tags t USING (id)
GROUP  BY t.parent_id;
```

It should work this way:

```
SELECT 25 AS keyword_id, count(DISTINCT m.id) AS total, t.parent_id
FROM  (
    SELECT m.id, unnest(m.taglist) AS tag_id
    FROM   mentions m
    WHERE  m.search_id = 4
    AND    25 = ANY (m.taglist)
    ) m
JOIN   tags t ON t.id =  m.tag_id
GROUP  BY t.parent_id;
```

I also added back the `DISTINCT` to your `count()` that got lost along the way in your query.

Comment: When I try to run your first query, I get the following error:
`ERROR:  column "tag_id" specified in USING clause does not exist in right table`

Comment: OK I changed the code to the following and it works:

`SELECT 25 AS keyword_id, count(m.id) AS total, t.parent_id AS tag_id
FROM  (
    SELECT  unnest(m.taglist) AS id
    FROM    mentions m
    WHERE   m.search_id = 4
    AND     25 = ANY (m.taglist) 
    ) m 
JOIN   tags t  USING (id)
GROUP  BY t.parent_id;`

But it again generates different results than the original query.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
...
tags t INNER JOIN
(SELECT UNNEST(taglist) as idd) a ON t.id = a.idd
...
```