# SELECT statement returning unqualified column names

Tags: sql, postgresql, naming-conventions, alias

I'm having difficulties  managing the queries like this:

```
SELECT c.id, p.id FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```

This query will return following set:

```
 id | id
----+----
 49 |  1
```

Is there any way to make it return `c.id` and `p.id` for column names? This one doesn't work:

```
SELECT c.id as c.id, p.id as c.id FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```

Or is this my final solution?

```
SELECT c.id as c_id, p.id as p_id FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id AS "c.id", p.id AS "p.id" FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```

or simply:

```
SELECT c.id "c.id", p.id "p.id" FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: See [7.3.2. Column Labels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-select-lists.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

With a proper **naming convention** you would rarely have to deal with this problem to begin with.

I suggest to use something like this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE claim (claim_id serial PRIMARY KEY, ...);

CREATE TABLE procedure (procedure_id serial PRIMARY KEY, ...);
```

`"id"` is a *very bad choice* for a column name. Unfortunately, some half-wit ORMs use this anti-pattern. Avoid it where you can.

Related:
[Join one to many and retrieve single result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468623/join-one-to-many-and-retrieve-single-result/12469295#12469295)
[Using UNNEST with a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054925/using-unnest-with-a-join/16070732#16070732)

Comment: I know it is. However, I didn't designed nor the databases, nor the system (and it is already in the use for a long time).

Answer (score 1):

And the last answer that is missing here which i believe is more correct approach is to use brackets [ ]

```
SELECT c.id AS [c.id], p.id AS [p.id]
FROM claim c, procedure p LIMIT 1;
```